# Offset text cursor with infield graphics?

Tags: html, css

I am doing the Google project on the Odin Project web dev tutorial, and I have put the search input box in with the magnifying glass, but the text cursor appears over the magnifying glass SVG image. Is there a method in CSS or HTML to offset the text cursor to the right?

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: text-indent:20px can also do the job

Comment: Thank you @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `padding-left` on the input element.

Generic example:

```css
input {
  padding-left: 20px; // Or however far you want the cursor to be offset
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input"/>
```

Comment: Omg! Cannot believe I missed that. That works, thank you. Sorry I cannot upvote yet, not enough rep :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can just add a padding left to the input equal or greater than the icon's width.
Example

```css
input {
   background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/20') no-repeat left center transparent ;
   padding-left:20px;
   }
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: This also works, and is quite clever. I never thought to put a background in the input field. I will defs use this method in future. Thank you.

Comment: @TrannyCyborg well i've put a background there to illustrate the solution. But regardless how you put the image there ( background, absolute positioning and so on ) padding is the solution